# Programming cc2530 on Linux

Tags: embedded, texas-instruments, firmware

I am trying to program a cc2530 mcu, all the example software and libraries are provided for IAR, but since I am on ubuntu, I am unable to use it, I have installed sdcc but I am still unclear as to how should I go about debugging codes and where can I get hardware abstraction libraries and linker script.

Comment: Any updates about building cc2530 projects using Linux environment?

Answer (score 2):

One simple solutions would be to download and configure Eclipse CDT for Ubuntu. Last year I was able to configure a Eclipse to do embedded development for TIVA TM4C123 ARM Cortex M4 processor.  I used Open On-Chip Debugging called [openocd](http://openocd.org/).  To a large extend you will be doing some ground breaking work. Communities like [Embedded Systems](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70800/embedded-systems?referrer=ZOCwVVz941jYYbSaWI8KwQ2) and Electronic SE are here to help you. When you are successful post the steps so other could benefit. Below are some references that might help you.  Good luck.

**References:**

- [Open On-Chip Debugging](http://openocd.org/)
- [How To: Develop on the TI Tiva LaunchPad using Linux](http://chrisrm.com/howto-develop-on-the-ti-tiva-launchpad-using-linux/)
- [CC2530 Contiki/6LowPan port](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Getting_started_with_Contiki_and_CC2530#CC2530_Contiki.2F6LowPan_port)
- [How to burn .hex intel format file on cc2530 EB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674556/how-to-burn-hex-intel-format-file-on-cc2530-eb)
- [Getting Started with the TI Stellaris LaunchPad on Linux](http://www.jann.cc/2012/12/11/getting_started_with_the_ti_stellaris_launchpad_on_linux.html)

Comment: I have added sdcc plugin to eclipse, and i am going through contiki files to see how it works, as far as debugging goes, openocd does not support cc2530 (it supports cc2538). I will have to use printf's i guess.. Thanksa lot. :)

Comment: My pleasure, I hope you will document and post your learning. You can request for cc2530 support on openocd.